# Preventing Extra blank page when formating xslt to prepare word file

Tags: xml, xslt

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong: formatting this xslt to prepare word document it throws next blank page even it have lots of space at the bottom. Event i have tried to manage margin and spaces through styling.
Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Invoices>
  <Invoice InvoiceId="12" JobId="1" AppraisalRef="JOBRefNo#1" invoicedescription="XXXXX" createdYear="2016" createdMonthName="May" createdMonth="5" createdDayName="Wednesday" createdDay="25" AccountName="rahul" Address1="adline1" Address2="Addline 2" Address3="addline 3" City="city" Region="region" PostalCode="110040">
    <InvoiceLinedesc linedesc="yyyy" lineamount="11.11" />
    <InvoiceLinedesc linedesc="xzy" lineamount="12.00" />
    <InvoiceLinedesc linedesc="abc" lineamount="100.00" />
    <InvoiceLinedesc linedesc="pqr" lineamount="120.00" />
    <InvoiceLinedesc linedesc="coer" lineamount="-100.00" />
    <InvoiceLinedesc linedesc="axz" lineamount="-50.00" />
    <InvoiceLinedesc linedesc="jhsdf" lineamount="100.00" />
    <InvoiceLinedesc lineamountsum="193.11" />
  </Invoice>
</Invoices>
```

And this one is XSLT code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:variable name="currencyFormat" select="'$#,###.00'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="companyName" select="'Lyon &amp; Turnbull'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="logoUrl" select="Request.Url.Scheme + '://' + Request.ServerVariables['HTTP_HOST'] + '/assets/images/logo_new.png'"/>
  <xsl:template match="Invoices">
    <HTML>
      <HEAD>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"/>
        <style>

          /* Font Definitions */
          @font-face
          {font-family:"Cambria Math";
          panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
          @font-face
          {font-family:Calibri;
          panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
          @font-face
          {font-family:Tahoma;
          panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
          @font-face
          {font-family:"Gotham Bold";
          panose-1:0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;}
          @font-face
          {font-family:"Gotham Book";
          panose-1:0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;}
          @font-face
          {font-family:"Gotham Light";
          panose-1:0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;}
          /* Style Definitions */
          p, li, div
          {
          margin: 0pt;
          font-size:12.0pt;
          font-family:"Gotham Book","sans-serif";
          display:inline-block;
          }

          p.Subtitle
          {
          font-size:10.0pt;
          font-family:"Gotham Book","sans-serif";
          font-style:italic;
          }

          p.Bold
          {
          font-family:"Gotham Bold","sans-serif";
          font-weight:bold;
          }

          p.DoubleHeight
          {
          font-size:10.0pt;
          margin-top:24.0pt
          }

          p.NoHeight
          {
          font-size:10.0pt;
          margin-top:0pt
          }

          p.SingleHeight
          {
          font-size:10.0pt;
          margin-top:12.0pt
          }

          p.Italic
          {
          font-style:italic;
          }

          h1
          {
          margin-top:48.0pt;
          margin-right:0cm;
          margin-bottom:0cm;
          margin-left:0cm;
          page-break-after:avoid;
          font-size:22.0pt;
          font-family:"Gotham Bold","sans-serif";
          font-weight:bold;
          }

          h2
          {
          margin-top:24.0pt;
          margin-right:0cm;
          margin-bottom:12.0pt;
          margin-left:0cm;
          page-break-after:avoid;
          font-size:12.0pt;
          font-family:"Gotham Book","sans-serif";
          font-weight:normal;
          }

          table
          {
          margin: 0;
          border-collapse:collapse;
          border-spacing:0;
          padding: 0;
          width: 100%;
          }

          td
          {
          padding:0 10pt 0 0;
          vertical-align: top;
          }

          table.Footer
          {
          width: 100%;
          }

          p.Footer
          {
          font-size:9px;
          font-family:"Gotham Light","sans-serif";
          }

          @page WordSection1
          {
          size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
          margin: 0.0pt 72.0pt 0pt 72.0pt;    /* US: 2.25in 1in 1in 1in; */
          mso-header: h1;
          mso-footer: f1;
          }

          div.WordSection1
          {
          page:WordSection1;
          }
          td.logo1
          {
          opacity:0.4;
          }
        </style>
      </HEAD>
      <body lang="EN-GB">
        <div class="WordSection1">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div style='margin-left: -20in; margin-right: -10in;'>
                  <div style='mso-element:header;' id='h1' >
                    <img width='200' height='40' src="/images/new_logo.png" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="logo1" style='margin-left: 5.2in;align:right;'>
                  <img width='100' height='100' src="/assets/images/BarcodeImg.png" />
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

          <br/>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td  align="right" style='font-size: 8px;'>• • •</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div>
                  <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(Invoice/@createdMonthName,' ',Invoice/@createdDay,', ',Invoice/@createdYear )"/>
                  </p>
                  <br/>
                  <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Invoice/@AccountName"/>
                  </p>
                  <xsl:if test="Invoice/@Address1!=''" >
                    <p>
                      <xsl:value-of select="Invoice/@Address1"/>
                    </p>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="Invoice/@Address2!=''" >
                    <p>
                      <xsl:value-of select="Invoice/@Address2"/>
                    </p>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="Invoice/@Address3!=''" >
                    <p>
                      <xsl:value-of select="Invoice/@Address3"/>
                    </p>
                  </xsl:if>
                  <xsl:if test="Invoice/@City!=''" >
                    <p>
                      <xsl:value-of select="Invoice/@City"/>
                    </p>
                  </xsl:if>

                  <p>
                    <xsl:if test="Invoice/@Region!=''" >
                      <xsl:value-of select="concat(Invoice/@Region,', ')"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="Invoice/@PostalCode!=''" >
                      <xsl:value-of select="Invoice/@PostalCode"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                  </p>
                  <!--<xsl:if test="Invoice/@PostalCode!=''" >
                    <p>
                      <xsl:value-of select="Invoice/@PostalCode"/>
                    </p>
                  </xsl:if>-->
                </div>
              </td>
              <td style="align:right">

                <p align='right' style='font-size: 8.0pt;'>
                  1150 First Avenue Suite 150
                </p>
                <p align='right' style='font-size: 8.0pt;'>
                  King of Prussia, PA, 19406
                  <br/>
                </p>
                <p align='right' style='font-size: 8.0pt; color:#8CC63F;'>
                  +1 610 254 8400
                  <br/>
                </p>
                <p align='right' style='font-size: 8.0pt; color:#8CC63F;'>
                  info@abc.com
                  <br/>
                </p>
                <p align='right' style='font-size: 8.0pt;'>
                  abc.com
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <!--<h1 align='center'>
            INVOICE FOR APPRAISAL SERVICES
          </h1>-->
          <h2 style="font-size:12.0pt; text-align:center; font-family: Times;">
            <b>
              <xsl:value-of select="Invoice/@invoicedescription"/>
            </b>
          </h2>
          <table>
            <xsl:for-each select="Invoice/InvoiceLinedesc">
              <!--<p style='line-height:150%'>
                <span style="text-align: left; margin-right: 0pt;">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@linedesc"/>
                </span>
                <span style="text-align: right; margin-left: 0pt;">
                  <xsl:if test="number(@lineamount) = @lineamount" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@lineamount, $currencyFormat)"/>
                  </xsl:if>
                </span>
              </p>-->
              <tr>
                <td valign='top'>
                  <p style='line-height:150%'>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@linedesc"/>
                  </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <p style="text-align: right; margin-left: 32pt; line-height:150%">
                    <xsl:if test="number(@lineamount) = @lineamount" >
                      <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@lineamount, $currencyFormat)"/>
                    </xsl:if>
                  </p>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td with="50%">
                <p class="Bold"></p>
              </td>
              <td width="50%">
                <p style="text-align: right; margin-left: 32pt;">
                  <hr/>
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td with="50%">
                <p class="Bold"></p>
              </td>
              <td width="50%">
                <p style="text-align: right; margin-left: 32pt;">                 
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p class="Bold"></p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p style="text-align: right; margin-left: 32pt;">
                  Subtotal:
                  <xsl:if test="number(Invoice/InvoiceLinedesc/@lineamountsum) = Invoice/InvoiceLinedesc/@lineamountsum" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(Invoice/InvoiceLinedesc/@lineamountsum, $currencyFormat)"/>
                  </xsl:if>
                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p class="Bold"></p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p style="text-align: right; margin-left: 32pt;">
                  Deposit Received:

                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p class="Bold"></p>
              </td>
              <td>
                <p class="Bold" style="text-align: right; margin-left: 32pt;">
                  Balance Due:

                </p>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <br/>
          <p>
            Payment is due upon receipt. Accepted forms of payment: VISA, MasterCard, American Express, Discover, Personal or Corporate checks, Wire Transfer.
          </p>
          <br/>
          <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td>Please remit payment to:</td>
              <td>
                <!--Wire Instructions:-->
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Abc Pvt. Ltd.</td>
              <td>
                <!--Receiving Bank: PNC Bank-->
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>

            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>

              </td>
            </tr>
            <!--<tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                --><!-- --><!--
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                --><!--Beneficiary: --><!--
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                --><!--Beneficiary Account Number: --><!--
              </td>
            </tr>-->
          </table>
          <div style='margin-left: -20in; margin-right: -10in;'>
            <div style='mso-element:footer' id='f1'>
              <P style='font-size:6.0pt;'>
                • • •
              </P>
              <P style='font-size:8.0pt; font-family: Times;'>
                LONDON&#160;&#160;•&#160;&#160;NEW YORK&#160;&#160;•&#160;&#160;PHILADELPHIA&#160;&#160;•&#160;&#160;LOS ANGELES&#160;&#160;•&#160;&#160;ATLANTA&#160;&#160;•&#160;&#160;AMSTERDAM
              </P>            
              <br/>
              <P class='Footer' style='font-size:6.5pt;'>
                 is the trading name of abc Limited and its subsidiary companies. Abc is a company registered in England and Wales.
                <BR/>
                <BR/>
                Registered number: .  Registered office:  .  VAT.
                <BR/>
                <BR/>
                ©2015 . All Rights Reserved.
              </P>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </HTML>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what i tried to do: <xsl:strip-space  elements="Invoice"/> but got this error "White space cannot be stripped from input documents that have already been loaded. Provide the input document as an XmlReader instead."

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your input XML nor the HTML output so it all is a kind of guess, but one thing to try would be to add

```
<xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have added input xml.

Comment: have you tried if the strip-space will fix the misbehaviour?

Comment: yes but i didn't get which element to strip. I am not much handy, I will really appritiate if you can refer any material working with xslt to format ms word docs. Thanks

Comment: just add the line from the answer at the top of your stylesheet

Comment: I have tried the answer you provided, it still not working. I have also tried:   <xsl:strip-space elements="Invoice"/> but got this error "White space cannot be stripped from input documents that have already been loaded. Provide the input document as an XmlReader instead." I didn't get this error. Any idea what is wrong with it? Thanks for being involved in my problem.

Comment: hmm I see - you are talking about a "word file" but what you generate is HTML (word can of course open that, but the normal way would be a web browser). What xsl processor do you use, mine will cough about your xsl namespace that it wants to be `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform`but that probably is not the reason for the blank page. In firefox the page looks ok, but does not display the footer - I guess it has something to do with the mso-... stuff and I'm sorry I have no idea about that. Good luck....